# Scope in a jQuery each function

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I can't figure out why the scope of $elm is lost within the jQuery each loop.  The scope of $elm is solid on lines: 76,77 and then lost inside the loop at 78.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's an image showing the code.

[image: code]

I added this image (referring to my comments) as proof that just by referencing $elm in anyway that it is then available to me on the console.

[image: Reference to my comment below]

Comment: What do you mean "scope of $elm is lost"?  `$elm` should be accessible just fine inside the `.each()` handler.  `this` will have a different value (see my answer below for an explanation), but you can just access that same info via `$elem`.

Comment: WHO MINUSED MY QUESTION AND WHY?  This is why I don't care for stack so much because someone can come along and down vote you for a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Its lost, its undefined within $.each loop.

Comment: Where is `this` being referenced within the loop? I don't see how it's getting "lost"

Comment: Its $elm getting lost and now I think I understand the problem.  It may be a chrome browser console issue.  I've seen this before and will now test.  I'm actually testing if $elm is available on the console while paused within $.each.  Since $elm was not referenced in code and only from the console, the console is confused and can't find it.  Testing now... yep! just by referencing the $elm anywhere/anyhow (image 2) in the loop makes it available in the console.

Comment: @kstubs - I didn't downvote your question, but you completely failed to mention that the ENTIRE issue was one of Chrome dev tools which lets lots of people waste lots of time trying to figure out what's going on. When you leave out critically important information which defines the scope of your problem, it is not surprising that your question get downvoted.  It was an incomplete question for most of its life.  Plus "scope is lost" is completely vague.  It did not describe your actual problem either.  You wrote a question that was not very clear - thus you got downvoted for it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I appreciate the feedback.  I did not know that the issue was Chrome dev tools issue at first (and it may in fact not be Chrome dev tools issue, but a valid optimization technique by javascript).  At first I thought it was a jQuery issue, and my lack of proficiency with the language brought me here to to ask.  My question could have been clearer.

Comment: @kstubs - Your problem was "seeing the value of `$elm` in the chrome dev tools".  That's what you were trying to do and was the actual problem statement.  You should have stated the problem as such.  A simple `console.log($elm)` would have shown you that the value is actually available in the `.each()` handler.  In the future, use a watch expression to see the value of a variable in a parent scope.  Parent scoped variables are not automatically shown to you in the debugger unless you specifically request them with a watch expression.

Comment: @jfriend00 I answered my own question.  Again, your additional feedback is much appreciated and you are 100% correct in stating:  Your problem was "seeing the value of $elm in the chrome dev tools".  Had this only been clear to me when I originally posted, all would be peachy keen!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

As it turns out, the real issue what the the OP wasn't seeing the value of the `$elm` automatically listed in the Chrome debugger when at a breakpoint inside the `.each()` loop.  This is because only variables used in the actual local scope are shown by Chrome in the `scope variables` section of the debugger and `$elm` at that point was in a parent scope, not in the local scope.

One can see any variable that is in scope, including variables in a parent scope, by putting the variable's name into a watch expression.

---

`jQuery.each()` sets `this` to the item being iterated in the `.each()` callback.  If you want the outer `this` to be accessible, a common work-around is to do:

```
var self = this;
```

And, then refer to `self` inside the `.each()` handler.

But, since you're already doing:

```
var $elm = this;
```

You can just use `$elm` just fine inside the `.each()` handler function.

---

In javascript, you should remember that ALL function calls change the value of `this` according to how the function is called.

---

It sounds to me like you should check what `this` is set to before you assign it to `$elm` as it's probably wrong there.  If that's the case, then the issue is likely in how you are calling `recurseHtml()` which is causing you to lose the desired value of `this`.

Remember that, in Javascript, EVERY function call changes the value of `this` according to how the function is called.  A regular function call clears the value of `this` (to either the global object or `undefined` if running in strict mode).  A method call sets `this` to be the object that the method was called on.  One can use `.apply()` or `.call()` or `.bind()` to specify the exact value of `this`.

Comment: "this" is what I am doing, but setting it to $elm as you have noted, yet it is still undefined.  Perhaps I'm doing something stupid (obviously) so I'll keep poking around.

Comment: @kstubs - The value of `$elm` will not change from the value it had when you assign it to when the code gets inside the `.each()` handler.  So, if it isn't what you want inside the `.each()` handler, then it wasn't right up above where you assigned it to `$elm` and thus the problem occurred when you called `recurseHTML`.  Do you realize that ALL function calls in Javascript reset the value of `this` according to how the function is called.  If it's just a normal function call, then `this` will be set to either the global object or `undefined` if running in strict mode.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've answered my own question above in comments.  The issue turns out to either be a Chrome dev tools issue, or its expected, such as that is how chrome compiles and optimizes code (as in, throws away unreferenced globals within internal scopes).

Comment: I understand the OP's problem/issue. If you have a construct as he has created and pause inside the .each() loop in Chrome debugging tools and ask for the value of $elm, you *can* get undefined. I have seen this and fixed it exactly the same way, by just referencing $elm in the .each() somewhere.

Comment: @kstubs - so then you should either delete your question or (when SO timing allows) submit your own answer since you no longer need anyone else to spend any time on this question.  I see that my effort was pretty much misdirected because you did not explain that this was an issue in chrome dev tools.

Comment: @KevinBrown - you can also just set a watch express for `$elm` and as they can see any variable that is currently in scope.  Because `$elm` is in a parent scope once you're in the `.each()` callback, it is not automatically shown to you in the debugger without explicitly asking to see its value with something like a watch expression.  This is not uncommon because all variables currently in scope (including all parent scopes) can be a very large set of variables (particularly including all global variables) which ruins the use of a nice compact list.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of $elm is not lost or undefined, it is just not available from the dev tools console if $elm has not been referenced in code at that scope.  By referencing $elm I have proven that the scope was never lost and is indeed "in scope".

Comment: It is available just fine if you put `$elm` in a watch expression.  it isn't shown automatically in the `scope variables` section of the chrome debugger unless it is used in the current scope.  This is likely a debugger usability optimization so that the `scope variables` section doesn't contain hundreds/thousands of variables that are not being used in the current scope.  In the future, just use a watch expression to see the value of any parent scoped variable.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .each create a callback **function** for each elements of array like:

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Try create a global var. Example:

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {

  if(value == 52) {
     xxx = 'value here'; //don't use "var xxx" if you need pass the value to the next iteration
     }

  console.log(xxx);

});
```

More details about Javascript Scope here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp